# Remember password with Azure AD authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a .NET Core 2.1 web application which uses .NET Identity. I use Azure AD to authenticate users. Client needs ability to remember password, so that they do not have to enter it every time. Is there a way to persist user's login with Azure AD in my web app?

Workflow: User clicks the login button, redirected to Microsoft login page where they enter their Azure AD credentials to authenticate, if login successful, redirected back to web application.

Right now, user has to enter username and password every time they use the application. They can save their password or login with Microsoft, but they still need to visit Microsoft's login page. How can I save their login in web application and avoid redirecting to Microsoft's login page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user can check "remember password" when logging in to avoid needing to enter the password again.

You cannot, however, skip the sign-in page. You can customize the appearance but redirecting there is unavoidable.

You can request this feature on User Voice if you wish. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will request this feature on User Voice. Cheers!

Comment: No problem :) I'll follow up with the Product Team on this as well. A lot of people have been asking about this lately.